# KeyError 3 in python when more dictionaries are added

Tags: python, arrays, random, keyerror

I wrote the following code. The code is running well. But when I add `yt[i]=y[i-1]+delta(R1,R2)` it gets an error:

`yt[i]=y[i-1]+delta(R1,R2)
KeyError: 1`

the function `a` is just an example and is not the real one.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import *

x  = { 0: 0.3 }
xt = {}
N=10
y  = { 0: 0.2 }
yt = {}

def a(z,s):
    return sqrt(z)+s

def delta(r1,r2):
        sig=0.055
        d=sig*(np.sqrt(-2*np.log(r1))*np.cos(np.radians(r2)))
        return d

for i in range(1,N):
    R1=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    R2=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    R3=np.random.uniform(0,1)

    xt[i]=x[i-1]+delta(R1,R2)
    yt[i]=y[i-1]+delta(R1,R2)

    if a(xt[i],yt[i])>R3:
        x[i]=xt[i]
        print('f')
    else:
        x[i]=x[i-1]
        print('s')

    print(x[i], delta(R1,R2), i)
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The code is raising a `KeyError` because in the second iteration of the for loop, `i=2` and `y={0: 0.2}`. What do you expect `y[i-1]` to be in the second iteration? Assign that value to `y[i-1]`.

Comment: @phihag well, for `x  = { 0: 0.3 }` it works correctly, why it gets error for `y`? `y` is exactly similar to `x` but is a different parameter.

Comment: @phihag  for `i=1` `y` is `0.2`, for `i=2` `y` is `0.2+delta` and so on.

Comment: There are no arrays in your code. You are working with a `dict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated. And do you know any solution, Please?

Comment: Because you never set a value for `y[1] = ...`... so it throws a key-error. For `x` you do in your `if...else...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for `x` because the `if`/`else` block in the lower part updates `x` to include a value for `x[i]` (which will be checked on the next iteration as `x[i-1]`). There's no such update to the `y` dict, so on the second pass, `y[i-1]` is not available.

You probably need to add lines like `y[i]=yt[i]`, either in the existing `if`/`else` blocks, or in an equivalent one that has it's own logic.

Comment: Oops, you mean that the whole problem was about adding `y[i]=yt[i]` in the blocks? Weird and perfect.